# Why does black text contain orange and light blue pixels on a computer?

Tags: display

On a computer screen, if you zoom in with the magnifier, you start noticing that all the black text contain light orange and light blue pixels around each letter. But why does it do this, rather than make the entire word black?

Answer (score 2):

Its [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) which causes the orange and blue pixels on the left and right sides of letters respectfully.   See the examples on the same [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering#Examples).

thanks to Dan D who corrected my mistake

Comment: No, it is not anti-aliasing; it's [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) which causes the orange and blue pixels on the left and right sides of letters respectfully. See [the examples on the same page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering#Examples).

Comment: you know, you are completely right.  Changing my answer... However I know this is a dupe on this site.  Not going to bother looking for it though.